# Backwards Compatible Android Application?

Tags: android

I have a simple android application that has a lockscreen widget. Apparently, lockscreen widgets were added in Android 4.2. My problem is that my SDK levels are between 16 and 19 due to this widget but I want my app to be available on more versions of android aside from 4.2 - 4.4. Is there any way to make it so that if the person isn't using 4.2 or later than they just don't get a lockscreen widget?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: if the person isn't using 4.2 or later than they just don't get a lockscreen widget?(not to appear on their screen?), can u make it a bit more clear that sentence?,again sorry

Comment: Meaning if your device is running Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) for example, you won't have access to the lockscreen widget because only 4.2 supports those widgets. My SDK levels are at 16 - 19 because I don't know how to support devices with 3.0 AND 4.2. Make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the SDK version of the device running the application then compare it to OS 4.2

```
int userAPI = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (userAPI >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
// enable lockscreen wdget
} else{
// disable lockscreen widget
}
```

This will disable widgets on any OS less than 4.2